# AngularJs Как получить все id из $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, scope

Помогите, пожалуйста, с контроллером в Angular.
В рельсовом приложении на странице есть силекты: группы систем и системы. Системы имеют оборудование, группы систем имеют системы. Когда я выбираю группу систем, я хочу, чтобы загрузилось оборудование всех систем, принадлежащих этой группе систем. В данный момент оборудование показывается только в случае выбора его системы.

```
 $scope.loadEquipments = (complex_id, object) ->
  if object == 'group'
    $scope.systems = SystemResource.where
      ppr_group_system_id: complex_id
    # load equipment of system
    $scope.equipments = EquipmentResource.where
      ppr_system_id: $scope.systems

  else if object == 'system'
    # load equipment of system
    $scope.equipments = EquipmentResource.where
      ppr_system_id: complex_id
  else
    $scope.equipments      = []
    $scope.equipment_works = []
```

То есть вместо ppr_system_id: $scope.systems мне нужно передавать что-то типа $scope.systems.id. Либо каким-то другим вариантом.

Comment: что за язык тут используется? что такое `$scope.systems`? что такое `EquipmentResource`? как определена функция `where`? что должно получиться в `$scope.equipments`? какая версия ангуляра? и можно еще html добавить в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно требовалось что-то в этом роде. Группировку сделал коряво, лучше конечно же написать свой фильтр.
Две группы, четыре системы, оборудования восемь шт. 
Что-то я не понял, почему первый селект имеет всего два элемента, а изначально пустой.

```
    <div ng-controller="equipCtrl">
        <select ng-model="grupid">
            <option value="{{grup.name}}" ng-repeat="grup in grups">{{grup.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="" ng-repeat="equip in equips | filter:grupid">{{equip.equip}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

formEditor.controller('equipCtrl', 
    ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

            $scope.grups = [];
            var grupid = [];
           $http.get('/js/equip.json')
                .then(function(resp){
                    // получаем список оборудования
                    $scope.equips = resp.data;
                    // перебираем и формируем список групп
                    angular.forEach($scope.equips, function(item, key) {
                        if(grupid.indexOf(item.grup.id) === -1){
                            $scope.grups.push({"id":item.grup.id, "name":item.grup.name});
                        }
                        grupid.push(item.grup.id);
                    });
                    console.log($scope.grups);
                });


    }]);



//json
[{
    "equip": "equip_name1",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "1",
    "grup":{"id":"1","name":"g1"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name2",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "1",
    "grup":{"id":"1","name":"g1"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name3",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "2",
    "grup":{"id":"1","name":"g1"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name4",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "2",
    "grup":{"id":"1","name":"g1"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name5",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "3",
    "grup":{"id":"2","name":"g2"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name6",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "3",
    "grup":{"id":"2","name":"g2"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name7",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "4",
    "grup":{"id":"2","name":"g2"}
},
{
    "equip": "equip_name8",
    "property":{
        "prop":"val"
    },
    "system": "4",
    "grup":{"id":"2","name":"g2"}
}
]
```

Comment: а вы же знаете что для `select` рекомендуют не `ng-repeat` а `ng-options`?

Comment: Теперь знаю, что для select надо использовать ng-options, благодарю.